# Kernel panic when trying to port android image for imx6ul board

Tags: embedded-linux

I am trying to build android image for nxp imx6ul board. I downloaded android_O8.0.0_1.0.0 tar from github, created mx6ul directory and build it for imx6ul. At present NXP doesnt have android support for imx6ul, so I am trying on my own looking onto sabresd board.

I am very new to android and Linux. I followed NXP docs to create the image. Build was successfully completed. when I tried to download on SD card and boot it gave me following log

```
uuc invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x24200ca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE), nodemask=0, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
CPU: 0 PID: 102 Comm: uuc Not tainted 4.9.11+ #1
Hardware name: Freescale i.MX6 UltraLite (Device Tree)
[<8010ed50>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<8010b274>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14)
[<8010b274>] (show_stack) from [<803aea6c>] (dump_stack+0x80/0x9c)
[<803aea6c>] (dump_stack) from [<801feb98>] (dump_header.constprop.4+0x64/0x1a0)
[<801feb98>] (dump_header.constprop.4) from [<801bf2cc>] (oom_kill_process+0x2d0/0x4b4)
[<801bf2cc>] (oom_kill_process) from [<801bf784>] (out_of_memory+0xd8/0x41c)
[<801bf784>] (out_of_memory) from [<801c3d4c>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask+0xb5c/0xbb8)
[<801c3d4c>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask) from [<801d251c>] (shmem_getpage_gfp.constprop.7+0x504/0xa00)
[<801d251c>] (shmem_getpage_gfp.constprop.7) from [<801bb354>] (generic_perform_write+0xb8/0x1a0)
[<801bb354>] (generic_perform_write) from [<801bcb18>] (__generic_file_write_iter+0x100/0x1f0)
[<801bcb18>] (__generic_file_write_iter) from [<801bccfc>] (generic_file_write_iter+0xf4/0x208)
[<801bccfc>] (generic_file_write_iter) from [<80201140>] (__vfs_write+0xbc/0x114)
[<80201140>] (__vfs_write) from [<80201e98>] (vfs_write+0xa0/0x168)
[<80201e98>] (vfs_write) from [<80202bec>] (SyS_write+0x3c/0x90)
[<80202bec>] (SyS_write) from [<801076c0>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x3c)
Mem-Info:
active_anon:2018 inactive_anon:114206 isolated_anon:0
 active_file:0 inactive_file:0 isolated_file:0
 unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
 slab_reclaimable:471 slab_unreclaimable:987
 mapped:559 shmem:116160 pagetables:12 bounce:0
 free:408 free_pcp:40 free_cma:0
Node 0 active_anon:8072kB inactive_anon:456824kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB mapped:2236kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB shmem:464640kB writeback_tmp:0kB unstable:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
Normal free:1632kB min:1652kB low:2064kB high:2476kB active_anon:8072kB inactive_anon:456824kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:524288kB managed:507900kB mlocked:0kB slab_reclaimable:1884kB slab_unreclaimable:3948kB kernel_stack:544kB pagetables:48kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:160kB local_pcp:160kB free_cma:0kB
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0
Normal: 4*4kB (UE) 4*8kB (UM) 5*16kB (UM) 29*32kB (UM) 9*64kB (U) 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB 0*8192kB 0*16384kB 0*32768kB = 1632kB
116160 total pagecache pages
0 pages in swap cache
Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Free swap  = 0kB
Total swap = 0kB
131072 pages RAM
0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
4097 pages reserved
81920 pages cma reserved
[ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
[  102]     0   102      467      316       6       0        0             0 uuc
Out of memory: Kill process 102 (uuc) score 2 or sacrifice child
Killed process 102 (uuc) total-vm:1868kB, anon-rss:132kB, file-rss:4kB, shmem-rss:1128kB
oom_reaper: reaped process 102 (uuc), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
/linuxrc: line 44:   102 Killed                  uuc
file-storage invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x24002c2(GFP_KERNEL|__GFP_HIGHMEM|__GFP_NOWARN), nodemask=0, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00008900

---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00008900

CPU: 0 PID: 82 Comm: file-storage Not tainted 4.9.11+ #1
Hardware name: Freescale i.MX6 UltraLite (Device Tree)
[<8010ed50>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<8010b274>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14)
[<8010b274>] (show_stack) from [<803aea6c>] (dump_stack+0x80/0x9c)
[<803aea6c>] (dump_stack) from [<801feb98>] (dump_header.constprop.4+0x64/0x1a0)
[<801feb98>] (dump_header.constprop.4) from [<801bfa3c>] (out_of_memory+0x390/0x41c)
[<801bfa3c>] (out_of_memory) from [<801c3d4c>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask+0xb5c/0xbb8)
[<801c3d4c>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask) from [<801ef38c>] (__vmalloc_node_range+0xec/0x20c)
[<801ef38c>] (__vmalloc_node_range) from [<801ef73c>] (__vmalloc_node.constprop.13+0x40/0x50)
[<801ef73c>] (__vmalloc_node.constprop.13) from [<801ef7d8>] (vmalloc+0x24/0x34)
[<801ef7d8>] (vmalloc) from [<8058eda4>] (utp_user_data_alloc+0x14/0x60)
[<8058eda4>] (utp_user_data_alloc) from [<80591410>] (fsg_main_thread+0x608/0x22f8)
[<80591410>] (fsg_main_thread) from [<8014a9b4>] (kthread+0xd0/0xf0)
[<8014a9b4>] (kthread) from [<80107778>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x3c)
Mem-Info:
active_anon:1948 inactive_anon:114211 isolated_anon:0
 active_file:0 inactive_file:0 isolated_file:0
 unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
 slab_reclaimable:471 slab_unreclaimable:987
 mapped:4 shmem:116160 pagetables:5 bounce:0
 free:412 free_pcp:37 free_cma:0
```

uuc is invoking killer. As, I read on the internet it is because of memory exhaust or optimization something.Can someone please help me pointing out, what can be the possible solution for this
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Asma

Comment: I've updated the answer below, see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

It does look like the OOM killer is getting invoked. Have you tried creating a leaner (smaller) Android image or stopping some programs from starting at boot?

You could try a couple of options:
- Disable Zygote at startup
- Build and run "tiny android": $ BUILD_TINY_ANDROID=true make -j4

See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-platform/XEDzxDGiFJA) for more ideas.

Comment: No. Could you please suggest me something how can I do that. I am very new in Linux and Android. this is my first program, I am working on.

Comment: Updated my answer with more details.